# Capturar evento de logon do Linux usando Java

Tags: java, linux, bash

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda para criar uma classe que capturasse o evento de logon de um usuário no Linux, utilizando o Java.

Comment: O quê este evento deveria retornar?

Comment: Olá Alca, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Da maneira que você descreveu sua pergunta faltaram informação para elaborarmos uma resposta concreta e apropriada. O que você já tentou? O que está precisando fazer? O que você tem atualmente em termos de código? Por que não fazer o contrário (um *shell script* que notifica o Java?). Enfim, por favor amplie sua pergunta com informações relevantes.

Answer (score 1):

No linux você pode criar um script que roda toda vez que o usuário logar. Você pode encontrar uma descrição [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97137/how-do-you-run-a-script-on-login-in-nix).

Depois você criar um script que executa seu programa java.
Mas puramente em java você não vai conseguir fazer isso.